# How to test the method that makes http request?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am writing tests in Laravel.
However, I am in trouble because I do not know how to test.
There is a method to make an http request as shown below.
How would you typically test this method?
Should I use a URL or mock that is actually accessible?

PHP 7.4.6
Laravel 7.0

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Exception;

class Hoge
{
    public function getText(string $url, ?string $user, ?string $password, string $ua): bool
    {
        $header = ["User-Agent" => $ua];
        $httpObject = $user && $password ? Http::withBasicAuth($user, $password)->withHeaders($header) : Http::withHeaders($header);

        try {
            $response = $httpObject->get($url);
            if ($response->ok()) {
                return $response->body();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionality that reaches out to other systems can be slow and make tests brittle. Nevertheless, you want to be sure that your `getText` method works as expected. I would do the following:

- Create a set of integration tests just for your `getText` method. These tests make actual http requests to a server to verify the expected behaviors. The web server don't have to be an external system. You could use php's [built in webserver](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) to provide test urls. You can find an article [here](https://medium.com/@peter.lafferty/start-phps-built-in-web-server-from-phpunit-9571f38c5045) that guides you in that direction.
- For every other functionality that uses the `getText` method, I'd mock that method to keep the tests fast.

Answer (score 1):

To create a new test case, you can use the `make:test` Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:test HogeTest
```

Then you can create your HogeTest, considering your headers are correct

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class HogeTest extends TestCase
{  
    public function hogeExample()
    {
        $header = ["User-Agent" => $ua];
        $response = $this->withHeaders([
            $header,
        ])->json('POST', $url, ['username' => $user, 'password' => $password]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
      // you can even dump response
      $response->dump();
    }
}
```

This is a simple example how you can use modify it as per your need.
See more in laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/testing)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Postman for web server / API testing. https://www.postman.com/downloads/